# AutoMapper Version="12.0.1" is not working with net7.0 in generic type object

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, automapper

```
[HttpGet("data")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SelectItem<int>>> GetDataList()
{
    var _record = await _Repo.GetMyRecordDataList().ToListAsync();
    //_record record is having proper data 
    var result = _record
        .Select(s => _mapper.Map<SelectItem<int>>(s));

    return result;
}
   CreateMap<ObjectOne, SelectItem<int>>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.UniqueId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TermCalendarID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DisplayText, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.TextTerm));
```

I am getting below result

```
[
  {
    "uniqueId": 0,
    "displayText": "",
    "isSelected": false
  },
  {
    "uniqueId": 0,
    "displayText": "",
    "isSelected": false
  } ]
```

but this is not correct .

But for  below one is working which is not generic

```
 var bookDtoList = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<BookDTO>>(books);
```

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.